# Split DF into several columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a column that I'm looking to split into several columns.  I'm not that familiar with regexp, so I'm not sure of the right way to go about this.

Sample data

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
                  ~player,
    "Eloy Jimenez OF CHW",
  "Fernando Tatis Jr SS SD"
  )
```

I'm looking to split the column where the Caps start.  For example:

```
output_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~col1, col2, col3,
  "Eloy Jimenez", "OF", "CHW",
  "Fernando Tatis Jr", "SS", "SD"
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `extract` from `tidyr` to capture the upper case characters from the end of the string

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   extract(player, into = str_c('col', 1:3), '^(.*)\\s+([A-Z]+)\\s+([A-Z]+)$')
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  col1              col2  col3 
#  <chr>             <chr> <chr>
#1 Eloy Jimenez      OF    CHW  
#2 Fernando Tatis Jr SS    SD
```

---

Or with `strcapture` from `base R`

```
strcapture('^(.*)\\s+([A-Z]+)\\s+([A-Z]+)$', df$player,
   data.frame(col1 = character(), col2 = character(), col3 = character()))
#               col1 col2 col3
#1      Eloy Jimenez   OF  CHW
#2 Fernando Tatis Jr   SS   SD
```

Comment: In some instances, col2 might be something like "1B", or "2B" and not "SS".  How would I amend to choose the 2nd part of the string whether it starts with a letter or number?

Comment: In that case, use `'^(.*)\\s+([[:alnum:]]+)\\s+([A-Z]+)$'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookarounds:

```
library(stringr)
str_split(string = "Eloy Jimenez OF CHW",
          pattern =  "( ?=([:upper:]{2,}))") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  trimws() %>% 
  stri_remove_empty()
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~player,
  "Eloy Jimenez OF CHW",
  "Fernando Tatis Jr SS SD"
)

setDT(df)

df[,tstrsplit(player,split=" (?=[A-Z]{2,})",perl=TRUE)]
#>                   V1 V2  V3
#> 1:      Eloy Jimenez OF CHW
#> 2: Fernando Tatis Jr SS  SD
```

Or `tidyr`

```
tidyr::separate(df,player,sep=" (?=[A-Z]{2,})",into=paste0("V",1:3))
```